# How to retrieve a Json object from SQL procedure in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a procedure like this

```
SELECT CQ.EnglishName, CQ.ArabicName, QA.ArabicName, QA.EnglishName, QA.ConditionQuestionId 
FROM ConditionQuestions AS CQ 
LEFT JOIN QuestionAnswers as QA ON CQ.Id = QA.ConditionQuestionId 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

I want to retrieve it in c#. I tried a lot of other answers but nothing works.
I am using something like that but it's not working and returning only a part of what should be returned although the procedure works completely fine.

```
var returnedObj = Salamtkdb.Database.SqlQuery<string>("sp_MostafaTesting");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using **SQL Server** - you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: ok thank you. This is just a test version and I'll change it in the end

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package, as it makes handling JSON trivial and I believe SQl server uses the same package. You could do the following:

Remove FOR JSON AUTO from your sp.

Create new class:

```
public class SpResult
{
 public string CqEnglishName {get;set;} 
 public ... CqArabicName ...
 ... QaArabicName ....
 ... QaEnglishName ...
 .... QaConditionQuestionId...
}
```

Add this class to your dbcontext:

```
public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SpResult>().HasNoKey();
}
```

and get result :

```
var result = Salamtkdb.SpResult.FromSqlRaw("Execute sp_MostafaTesting").ToArray();
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```